# JavaScript policy in keycloak

Tags: keycloak

How to find all the attributes present in identity.attributes?

```
var context = $evaluation.getContext();
var permission = $evaluation.getPermission();
var resource = permission.getResource();
var identity = context.getIdentity();
print(identity.attributes)

if (identity.id == resource.owner) {
    $evaluation.grant();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try adding this:

```
var attributes = identity.getAttributes();
print('user attributes: ' + attributes.toMap().keySet());
```